# Proof for proposition 4.5.13 in Artin's Algebra book (characteristic polynomial)

Tags: linear-algebra

[image: charpol artin]

the characteristic polynomial is defined as $\det(tI-A)$

$\det(tI-A)$ is $$\sum_{\text{perm} p}\text{sign }p a'_{1p1}....a'_{npn}$$

i.e. $p(t)=(t-a_{11})...(t-a_{n})+....=(t^n-(\text{trace }A)t^{n-1}+....)+...$

But how do we know that the constant part of the polynomial is equal to $(-1)^n\det A$ ?

Comment: I am a bit worried about the way you wrote $p(t) = (t-a_{11})\cdots (t-a_{nn})+\cdots $, by the way. In general, that first summand has not much to do with $p(t)$ unless $A$ is diagonalisable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that the constant term is $p_A(0) = \det(-A)=(-1)^n \det A$.